# Script To Query Local Policy Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

this is my first time auditing and hardening a Windows 2008 server.

I thought that i could query the registry settings on the box using a command like `reg query <registry name>` . However i didn't realize that local policies i wish to query cannot be done in this way. For example i cant find a way to query the following settings on the system from the command line. My goal is to script some of these settings. I don't wish to use the GUI Local Security Policy Management Console

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Advanced Audit Policy Configuration\Audit Policies

Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update
```

I have around 10 such policies i need to query. I `DONT` need to edit them. Can someone tell me how to do this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get-GPOReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gporeport?view=windowsserver2022-ps) powershel commandlet to export GPO to xml. And then parse it (for example with [Select-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7.3)) to check enabled policy settings.

Comment: It seems great for GPO (domain) but I don't see a way to access Local Group Policies with that.

Answer (score 0):

Local Group Policy on WIndows Server

### Administrative templates

The local policies are accessible via the Windows Registry.

E.g. for

```
User > Windows Components\Work Folders > Enables the use of Token Broker for AD FS authentication
```

Do

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WorkFolders!EnableTokenBroker"
```

To find the registry keys take a look at [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) (2017) or [Group Policy Settings Reference Spreadsheet for Windows Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104005) (2022).